the selected date range is not displaying in the textformfield
TextEditingController dateRangeController = TextEditingController();
_selectDate3(BuildContext context) async {
final pickedRange = await showDateRangePicker(
context: context,
firstDate: DateTime(2000),
lastDate: DateTime(2099),
builder: (context, child) {
return Theme(
data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
primary: Color(0xff00364D), // Customize color here
onPrimary: Colors.white, // Customize color here
onSurface: Colors.black, // Customize color here
),
),
child: child!,
);
},
);
if (pickedRange != null) {
  setState(() {
    dateRangeController.text = '${pickedRange.start.toLocal()} - ${pickedRange.end.toLocal()}';
  });
}

}
             Container(
               height: 39,
               width: 300,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   //color: boxColor
               ),
               child: TextFormField(
                 readOnly: true,
                 controller: dateRangeController,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                   suffixIcon: InkWell(
                     onTap: (){
                       _selectDate3(context);
                     },
                     child: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                   )
                 ),
               ),
               // child: IconButton(
               //   onPressed: () {
               //     _selectDate3(context);
               //   },
               //   icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
               // ),
             ),

the selected  date range is not displaying in the textformfield why? i want to  display the selected date range in that textform field
